# ActiveMQ performance in different Operating Systems

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, message-queue

I have tested activeMQ JMSProducer in some operating systems. The results are as follows:

```
AIX     - Persistent - around  50 messages per second
Solaris - Persistent - around  60 messages per second
Linux   - Persistent - around 500 messages per second
```

1. Is that normal behaviour because in Linux, it is much much faster? 
   `ActiveMQ Performance` document is only based on Linux.
2. And, does `Slow KahaDB access` slow down activeMQ performance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With persisted connections you are highly dependant on the performance of your hardware and how the OS will commit write to disk.  If you enable the write cache on your disk for example, this could be enough to explain the difference. If you used an SSD, I would expect performance to be at least 10x higher, regardless of the OS.

Comment: Hi @Peter Lawrey, does Slow KahaDB access effect activeMQ performance (rate of sending or receiving messages)?

Comment: I have haven't tried different DBs for activeMQ. I have just used the default which was ok for my needs.