# ActiveMQ performance for producing persistent text messages

Tags: activemq-classic, persistent

As advised on the webpage 
[activemq-performance-module-users-manual](http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-performance-module-users-manual.html) I've tried (on an Intel i7 laptop with Windows 7 OS and SSD drive) the performance of producing persistent messages on a ActiveMQ Queue :

```
mvn activemq-perf:producer -Dproducer.destName=queue://TEST.FOO -Dproducer.deliveryMode=persistent
```

against the default installation of activemq 5.12.1

The performance which I got is around 300-400 messages per second.
On the page [activemq-performance](http://activemq.apache.org/performance.html) I have been reading much higher numbers:

> When running the server on one box and a single producer and consumer thread in separate VMs on the other box, using a single topic we got around 21-22,000 messages/second using 1-2K messages.

On the other hand, when the messages are not persistent, the performance of the producer grows  to 49000 messages per second. `-Dproducer.deliveryMode=nonpersistent`

When the messages are sent asynchrounously.
    `-Dproducer.deliveryMode=persistent -Dfactory.useAsyncSend=true`
I get around 23000 messages sent per second.

From what I see here [stackoverflow-activemq-persistent-performance-on-different-operatiing-systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795293/activemq-performance-in-different-operating-systems) it makes a difference when running activemq on different OS.

Can somebody give me some tips for having a better performance for writing persistent activemq messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance of sending persistent messages is all about disk based IO as the message must be written to the disk prior to the broker signalling the client that the message send completed.  The faster the disk the better your throughput will be, all else being equal.

To work around some of this you can send persistent messages in transactional batches so that the send itself is complete and the synchronization point is reduced to the transaction boundary.

Depending on the size of the text messages you can also gain some performance by using compression, this can be turned on via a [option](http://activemq.apache.org/connection-configuration-uri.html) in the ActiveMQConnectionFactory.